# Button to copy the value of a string to the clipboard

Tags: android, string, button, clipboard

I'm modifying an old Android application.  I have a GPS lat and long being stored in a string value and displayed to the user in a non-editable text box when it resolves.  I want to add a button which simply takes the value of the string, and copies it to the clipboard.

I've looked at this:   [How to copy text programmatically in my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238284/how-to-copy-text-programatically-in-my-android-app)

But not sure how to implement it. Any help would be great, I haven't touched much development in this area recently!

Thanks

Edit:

```
    //Set button (inside oncreate method)
    Button button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.buttoncopylocation);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

//Code added in onClick method
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)   getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copied", mycoords);
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}
```

I'm getting this error:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqGSA.jpg

Comment: It will be helpful if you post that piece of code, where you want to set text in the clipboard.

Comment: @Trickster I've added code to assist.

Comment: Which API Level are you targeting? ClipData is available since API Level 11.

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>

Comment: look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027629/android-clipboard-code-that-works-on-all-api-levels). see also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version) for clarification of min and target sdk version

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If it is just Text, it is very simple.

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label","Your Text");
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

For further Information check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html#Copying)

Comment: This worked, thanks (changed slightly though): public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
      android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
      clipboard.setText(mycoords);
  
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score -1):

provide a context before

```
getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
```

like

```
Context context = ...;
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
```