# clipboardmanager, how to on android < 3

Tags: android, android-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android clipboard code that works on all API levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027629/android-clipboard-code-that-works-on-all-api-levels)

On android > 3, to copy text to clipboard I use this code:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
```

I didn't found how copy text using android < 3

thanks!

Comment: Pol, ClipboardManager was there from api 1 and deprecated in api 11. Maybe your problem is related to activitys or fragments, what error are you getting and where?

Comment: Solved with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027629/android-clipboard-code-that-works-on-all-api-levels thanks!