# how to copy a text to the Clipboard in android

Tags: android, android-view, textview

I want to copy some text in temprory memory :

```
TextView tv = (int)findViewById(R.id.txt);
String str = tv.getText().toString();
```

now how an I copy str in clipboard  ???

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238284/how-to-copy-text-programatically-in-my-android-app

Comment: http://android-snippets.appspot.com/copy-text-to-clipboard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [ClipboardManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html)

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.setText("text to clip");
} else {
    android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
    android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("text label","text to clip");
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `ClipboardManager`.

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html) the doc.

you have to call `setPrimaryClip` with a `ClipData`

Answer (score 0):

You may need [ClipboardManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html) and perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027629/android-clipboard-code-that-works-on-all-api-levels) could help.