# How to copy text to Clipboard from TextField in Android

Tags: android, clipboard

I want to copy text from `TextField` to `Clipboard`.
My TextField is named `txtDetails` and i have a button named `btnCopyToClipBoard`.I want to be able to copy the contents of my textfield to clipboard when i press the button.

Name Of InputBox Is "txtDetails"
Name Of Button Is "btnCopyToClipBoard"

```
String StrTemp  = txtDetails.getText();
```

So How We Can Set "OnClickListener" Of "btnCopyToClipBoard" To Copy Value In "StrTemp" To ClipBoard

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to copy a text to the Clipboard in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435151/how-to-copy-a-text-to-the-clipboard-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy text programmatically in my Android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238284/how-to-copy-text-programmatically-in-my-android-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use global class extends Application for example:

```
public class G extends Application
```

And Call In manifiest

and use

```
public static Context               context;

// OnCreate
context = getApplicationContext();
```

And Then Change That Line As:

```
 ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) G.context.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
```

Or Use

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getContext().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use ClipBoardManager's setText method:

```
String StrTemp  = txtDetails.getText();
btnCopyToClipBoard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", StrTemp);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
});
```

Comment: Unable, getSystemService in Unknown, can not use it in custom spinner