# Copy Paste not working in android 2.3.6 (Gingerbread)

Tags: android

I hava a button and an edittext box in my activity ,on pressing the button i am copying all the text in the edittext to the Clipboard . The code is working fine in all the devices i checked except in Samsung GT-S6802 running with android version 2.3.6 . 
I am unable to discover the issue . Pls help .

```
btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (edit.getText().length() > 0) {
                    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    clipboard.setText(edit.getText());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Text is Copied Press long to paste anywhere",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: when code is working fine then whats the issue?

Comment: The app is getting crashed in Samsung GT-S6802 on pressing that copy button .

Comment: is it possible to paste logcat?

Comment: Nopes!! i dont have the log as that device is not with me :(

Comment: is the api to copy is different in that version??

Comment: u may try a application with store logcat of device then may be u can understand whats the issue in that device

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the version greater than HoneyComb ,the package of ClipboardManager is changed to android.content.ClipboardManager from  android.text.ClipboardManager . Proper code is shown below .

```
 int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                            if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                                android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label",
                                        edit.getText());
                                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                            } else {
                                android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                                clipboard.setText(edit.getText());
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

probably class `android.content.ClipboardManager` is imported, which works only from API>=11 on. Since 2.3.6 is API 10, the app crashes I guess saying `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

See [Android clipboard code that works on all API levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027629/android-clipboard-code-that-works-on-all-api-levels) or [How to copy text programmatically in my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238284/how-to-copy-text-programatically-in-my-android-app/11012443#11012443)
for solution that work. Still, the dalvikvm reports an error because it tries to verify all classes, but the app does not crash.

To prevent loading of classes, which can't be verified, see http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html where the correct version dependent abstract class is instantiated at runtime.