# copy button that copy your textview not working

Tags: java, android

i have created a copy button succesfully that copy my textview but when i try it out it doesn't work even though the text copied to clipboard appears but still the textview haven't been copied

this is my code in SecondActivity.java containing the copy button

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


public void onClick(View arg0) { getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        



}
});

}
```

i hope you can help me and thanks in advance

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027629/android-clipboard-code-that-works-on-all-api-levels)

Comment: didn't help me unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching the clipboard text like this and see if you can get the text:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
String strCopiedText = clipboard.getText();
```

Once you are able to fetch the text set where ever you want to.

In case you want a desired text to be saved in the clipboard than use:

```
clipboard.setText(yourtextView.getText().toString());
```

Edited:

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
    public void onClick(View v) { 

        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
        String strCopiedText;
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "Text to Copy");
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip); 

            strCopiedText = (String) clipboard.getText(); 
            clipboard.setText(state2.getText().toString());

        } else{
            strCopiedText = (String) clipboard.getText(); 
            clipboard.setText(state2.getText().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what i did    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 public void onClick(View v) {   
     ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
     @SuppressWarnings({ "unused" })
  String strCopiedText  = (String) clipboard.getText();
     clipboard.setText(state2.getText().toString());

Comment: the app crah when i ress the copy button

Comment: i have min=11 max=19 and i'm using with a device that have api level 15